# Convert JQuery Data into HighChart Format

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am new in json ,I want create a HighChart,I have data in JSON format and i have converted it into  table format [below is data and column extracted from JSON ] .

### Venue    DateRange   Clicks

Yahoo Search     2010-04-01   2172 
Google                 2010-04-01     10830  
MSN                        2010-04-01   555 
SSP                            2010-04-01   0 
Yahoo Search        2010-04-02     1746 
Google                        2010-04-02     8508 
MSN                            2010-04-02   477 
Google                          2010-04-03     5061 
Yahoo Search          2010-04-03      1113 
MSN                              2010-04-03     192

i want create a JSON string in Following Format.How can i do this

```
xAxis: {categories: ['2010-04-01', '2010-04-02', ' 2010-04-03']},
series: [{
                name: 'Yahoo Search',
                data: [2172 ,1746,1113]
            }, 
{
                name: 'Google',
                data: [10830,8508,5061]
            },
 {
                name: 'MSN',
                data: [555,477,792]
            }, 
{
                name: 'SSP',
                data: [0,0,0]
            }]
```

My json data is here

```
{"schema":{"fields":[{"name":"NM_Venue","type":"STRING","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"name":"NM_DateRange","type":"STRING","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"name":"M_Clicks","type":"INTEGER","mode":"NULLABLE"}]},"totalRows":"10","rows":[{"f":[{"v":"Yahoo Search"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"2172"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Google"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"10830"}]},{"f":[{"v":"MSN"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"555"}]},{"f":[{"v":"SSP"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"0"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Yahoo Search"},{"v":"2010-04-02"},{"v":"1746"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Google"},{"v":"2010-04-02"},{"v":"8508"}]},{"f":[{"v":"MSN"},{"v":"2010-04-02"},{"v":"477"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Google"},{"v":"2010-04-03"},{"v":"5061"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Yahoo Search"},{"v":"2010-04-03"},{"v":"1113"}]},{"f":[{"v":"MSN"},{"v":"2010-04-03"},{"v":"192"}]}],
"result":{"schema":{"fields":[{"name":"NM_Venue","type":"STRING","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"name":"NM_DateRange","type":"STRING","mode":"NULLABLE"},{"name":"M_Clicks","type":"INTEGER","mode":"NULLABLE"}]},"totalRows":"10","rows":[{"f":[{"v":"Yahoo Search"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"2172"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Google"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"10830"}]},{"f":[{"v":"MSN"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"555"}]},{"f":[{"v":"SSP"},{"v":"2010-04-01"},{"v":"0"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Yahoo Search"},{"v":"2010-04-02"},{"v":"1746"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Google"},{"v":"2010-04-02"},{"v":"8508"}]},{"f":[{"v":"MSN"},{"v":"2010-04-02"},{"v":"477"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Google"},{"v":"2010-04-03"},{"v":"5061"}]},{"f":[{"v":"Yahoo Search"},{"v":"2010-04-03"},{"v":"1113"}]},{"f":[{"v":"MSN"},{"v":"2010-04-03"},{"v":"192"}]}]}}
```

Comment: send json encoded format let me check

Comment: @Stano He has created a table from json format data

Comment: yeah, your right. it's much simpler to get the data from the original JSON string than from [that table](http://jsfiddle.net/hrCnY/).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your existing JSON string to the new JSON string e.g. with this function:

```js
function makeJSONstring(jsonstr) {
    var rows = JSON.parse(jsonstr).rows;
    console.log(rows);
    var data = [];
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        data.push({
            Venue: rows[i].f[0].v,
            DateRange: rows[i].f[1].v,
            Clicks: rows[i].f[2].v | 0
        });
    }
    //console.log(data);
    var out = {
        xAxis: {
            categories: [ /*'2010-04-01', '2010-04-02', ' 2010-04-03'*/ ]
        },
        series: [ /*{ name: 'Yahoo Search', data: [2172 ,1746,1113] } , etc. */ ]
    };
    var cat = {}, ser = {}; // temporary variables
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // data[i].Vanue , data[i].DateRange , data[i].Clicks
        if (cat[data[i].DateRange] === undefined) {
            cat[data[i].DateRange] = true;
            out.xAxis.categories.push(data[i].DateRange);
        }
        if (ser[data[i].Venue] === undefined) {
            ser[data[i].Venue] = out.series.length;
            out.series.push({
                name: data[i].Venue,
                data: [data[i].Clicks]
            });
        } else {
            var index = ser[data[i].Venue];
            out.series[index].data.push(data[i].Clicks);
        }
    }
    //console.log(out);
    return JSON.stringify(out);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hrCnY/3/)

Or alternative example, where data are collected from the table is here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrCnY/1/)

Comment: Great, so I am also glad it helped, vivek :-)